# fallback rules with simple-html-dom

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

I'm trying to write a small scraper to do things more automatically,
so far it's been doing the job *nearly* perfect - i'm missing fallback rules for older pages)

i'll try to explain myself,
currently i'm picking up *title* with `$html->find('h1[class=TitWhite22]')`
but some of the pages contain older format where instead of being on class=Titwhite22 it might appear with class=textwhite16 (or any other class for that matter).

my basic function is:

```
foreach($html->find('h1[class=TitWhite22]') as $element){
    $titleName = $element->innertext;
}
```

how can i set a rule that if the specific class isn't there, it should attempt a different class ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below code may resolve your problem.

```
$count22 = 0;

foreach($html->find('h1[class=TitWhite22]') as $element)
{ 
 $count22 = $count22+1;
}

if($count22==0)
{
  $count16=0;
  foreach($html->find('h1[class=TexttWhite16]') as $element1)
  {
    $count16 = $count16+1;
  }
  if($count16==0)
  {
    $count12=0;  
    foreach($html->find('h1[class=TitWhite12]') as $element2)
    {
      $count12=$count12+1;
    }
    if($count12==0)
      echo "All Fail";
    else
    {
      foreach($html->find('h1[class=TitWhite12]') as $element2)
      {
        $titleName12= $element2->innertext;
      }
    }
  }
  else
  {
    foreach($html->find('h1[class=TexttWhite16]') as $element1)
    {
        $titleName16= $element2->innertext;
    }
  }  
}
else
{
   foreach($html->find('h1[class=TitWhite22]') as $element)
   { 
     $titleName22= $element->innertext;
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you - but as there are too many H1 with irrelevant classes, i was hoping to be able to simply define specific ones as a fallback other then take the wider approach.

Comment: then Please provide the class names for H1 to get the result

Comment: I'm looking for h1[class=TitWhite22], if not found then h1[class=TexttWhite16], if not found then h1[class=TitWhite12], if all fail then echo "all fail".

Comment: This is far less elegant solution then i have hoped for, but nonetheless - a fully working one. thank you for your help.